# Is UserExtendedProperties.GetValue user-specific or device-specific?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'd like to use UserExtendedProperties.GetValue to associate a user with a high score table in a game I'm working on. Reading [Microsoft's own API description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.userextendedproperties.getvalue(v=VS.92).aspx) I cannot work out whether this applies to a user (blah@live.com) or a physical device. Does anyone know?

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UserExtendedProperties.GetValue("ANID") is an anonymous ID based on the user's Live ID. So, the same Live ID logged in from multiple WP7 devices will have the same ANID.